# jQuery no conflict conflict with jQuery scripts?

Tags: jquery

If you import a javascript file that calls `jQuery.noConflict()`, will that cause errors with scripts you made that depend on jQuery's `$` shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will, as it will return `$` to whatever it pointed to previously (possibly `undefined`).

You could always encapsulate your code with...

```
(function($) {
    // `$` in here points to `jQuery` and `$.noConflict()` won't affect it.
}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Jquery reference of $ sign to something else (which i think you will because that is the purpose of noConflict) it will.

This is how you use it:

var $j =  jQuery.noConflict();

after this the $ for jquery would be $j